# Conditional filtering - google sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, conditional-statements, filtering

How do i filter data according to these rules:

1. Find first nonblank row in Col 1, insert value. Until that, all preceding rows in col 1, col 2, col 3 should be empty.
2. Find first nonblank row in Col 2, insert value. All rows for all the columns between first nonblank value in Col 1 and first nonblank value in Col 2 should be empty.
3. Find first nonblank row in Col 3, insert value. All rows for all the columns between first nonblank value in Col 2 and first nonblank value in Col 3 should be empty.

Repeat again from Col 1.

Result table should look like this:

[image: source and result table screen]

Thank you!

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1yLAa8xp4E-aRfvkSRMAaQ_E00UOsCLZHaLQw30DwArQ/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I have provided an alternative answer which is in script. if you can consider script as the solution, then kindly check if it works on you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure if this can be done in `Sheets` but this is actually very easy when done in `Apps Script`. If you can consider `Apps Script` solution, then feel free to use the code below.

#### Code:

```
function myFunction() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  // Modify range where the source table is
  var range = sheet.getRange('A1:C24');
  var data = range.getValues();
  // variable trackers
  var col1 = 1, col2, col3;

  data.forEach(function (row, index){
    // Skip checking the column headers
    if (index != 0) {
      // If first value of col1 was found, switch to col2 (So on and so forth)
      // If not first value of column after previous column checked, then overwrite with blank
      // Repeat this behavior until last row of data
      if(col1 && row[0]){
        col1 = '', col2 = 1;
      }
      else if(col2 && row[1]){
        col2 = '', col3 = 1;
      }
      else if(col3 && row[2]){
        col3 = '', col1 = 1;
      }
      else {
        data[index][0] = '';
        data[index][1] = '';
        data[index][2] = '';
      }
    }
  });
  // Overwrites the source table
  range.setValues(data);
}
```

#### Sample Output:

[image: output]

#### Note:

- If you want to have the output right beside the data, have `range.setValues(data);` changed into `range.offset(0, data[0].length).setValues(data);`, resulting into the output below.

#### Output:

[image: output2]

Answer (score 0):

guys,

thanks a lot for your responses! I have found workaround:

[image: screen]

There should be auxiliary table, which tells me on which row the cell im looking for is located:

For the first cell (number 6 in the screen):

```
=row(INDEX(B3:B26,MATCH(TRUE,ISNUMBER(B3:B26),0)))
```

Second cell (number 17 in the screen):

```
=row(INDEX((indirect("C"&J4&":C")),MATCH(TRUE,ISNUMBER((indirect("C"&J4&":C"))),0)))
```

Third cell (number 20 in the screen):

```
=row(INDEX((indirect("D"&K5&":D")),MATCH(TRUE,ISNUMBER((indirect("D"&K5&":D"))),0)))
```

Fourth cell (number 23 in the screen):

```
=row(INDEX((indirect("B"&L6&":B")),MATCH(TRUE,ISNUMBER((indirect("B"&L6&":B"))),0)))
```

Then, repeat second, third and fourth cell on and on.

Once i know location of desired cells, its easy to use index function to get actual values.

```
=index($B$4:$B26,J4-3,1)
=index($C$4:$C27,K5-3,1)
=index($D$4:$D28,L6-3,1)
```

And repeat on and on.

I know, its not the most elegant solution, in the end it is not exactly what i asked for, but found out that it works for me :)

Anyway, thanks for your help, at least im getting motivated to learn about apps script more :)